# db2 import from file csv

Tags: csv, import, db2

I made a simple example, but it does not work.
I connect to sample database

my file is ABC.csv

1;2

2;3

```
db2 import from "ABC.csv" OF DEL insert into abc(id,id2)
```

the import found the rows and it says that inserted.

but if `db2 select * from abc` no numbers appear but '-'

example

id id2

_   _

_   _

why?

the table abc is create as (id int, id2 int)

Comment: How many rows were imported according to DB2? What was the exact output?

Comment: Input and output are those shown above @data_henrik

Comment: The standard delimiter between column values is a comma (","), but you are using semicolon (";"). What is the exact DB2 output for the import command?

Comment: yes, if i change the delimiter ',' , its works.     thank you...    happen to know a db2 utility that shred XML file to relational table?   import or load can do it?         @data_henrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you either use the standard delimiter (comma, ",") in your data file or to adapt the delimiter using the COLDEL parameter.

`db2 import from "ABC.csv" OF DEL MODIFIED BY COLDEL; insert into abc(id,id2)`

Comment: thank you... you  know a db2 utility that shred XML file to relational table? import or load can do it?

Comment: ask in a separate question